# how to record exact recipe line in Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

I'm looking to record the exact commands used to build artifacts within a makefile.   I'd like this to be stored in a file for later consumption.   I am running into issues due to quotes.   Basically, what I want is:

```
define record_and_run_recipe
    @echo '$(2)' > $1
    $2
endef


all:
    $(call record_and_run_recipe,out.cmd,\
            @echo 'hello world "$$1"' )
    cat out.cmd
```

I would like this to output (exactly)

```
 @echo 'hello world "$1"'
```

Of course, the quotes end up matching with the quotes in the expansion of the variable, and this messes everything up.   (I get `@echo hello world` instead).   Bash doesn't like `'\''` either, so I can't simply do `$(2:'=\')`.   I also seem to have issues with `,` characters...

I'm not looking to debug the entire makefile, just dump a couple of recipes.  I'm wondering if anyone has a robust way of accomplishing this.

Comment: Try using make's `$(info ...)` function instead: make doesn't care about quotes.

Comment: The usual way to do this is to avoid non-echoing command (`@`) and then run your make command in a tool like `script`.

Comment: You can't use `$(2:'=\')` because first, that won't quote other chars and second, that kind of substitution replaces only _one_ element, at the end, not all the elements.  See my reply below: you need to use `subst` to replace all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment above, you can use GNU make's `$(info ...)` function.  It's not *exactly* clear from your example above what you want to do; why are you trying to put the output into a file, then cat it?  Is that important?

If you can't use `info`, the canonical way to handle quoting in shell is to surround the string with single quotes, then replace every single quote with `'\''`.  You say "bash doesn't like" that, but I don't know what that means.  Normally you'd do something like:

```
define record_and_run_recipe
    @echo '$(subst ','\'',$2)' > $1
    $2
endef
```

As far as commas you will absolutely have a problem with commas if you want to use the `$(call ...)` function.  The only way to avoid that is to put the string into a variable, like:

```
output = foo, bar
    ... $(call blah,$(output))
```

to "hide" the comma from `call`.

Comment: I'm looking for the file to be generated as a side effect of the recipe (and yes, I know it's not good practice to have side effects of recipes...).    Specifically, for every .o, I would like a .o.cmd file that holds the command used to generate the file.   This will be used in a subsequent code analysis tool.   So, unfortunately, I cannot parse the output of make to find this, and `$(info)` would not work for my purposes...

Comment: OK see my other suggestions

Comment: If you do `echo '\''` at a bash prompt, it matches the first quote with the second one (which is not escaped...), and it then sees the third quote, and prompts you for a second line...

Comment: The commas is not as big of an issue.    I don't have to worry about commas in variables, as parameter boundaries seem to  be determined before variable expansion.   It should therefore not be to hard to avoid manual commas in the recipe's I'm instrumenting.

Comment: Sorry, I had the `subst` command wrong.  It works in my updated version

Comment: Interesting -- that works great (the first quote terminates the quote string, then adds the escaped quote, then starts a new quote)...   My only question is why does `@echo '$(subst ','\'',$2)'`, but `@echo '$(2:'='\'')'` not work?

Comment: See my comment on your question.  A substitution reference is a form of `patsubst`, not `subst`.  `$(2:'='\'')` is the same as writing `$(patsubst %',%'\'',$2)` which is totally not what you want: it replaces _only_ the final `'` (if it exists) not _every_ `'`.  If you remove the `@` on your rules (using this is an anti-pattern, at least until your makefile works and even afterwards) you'll see what happens here.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html